# Having two html table cells total width stay within given width?

Tags: html, merge, html-table, width, cell

I have an html table using `colspan=2` to merge cells. I need to make sure merged cells have a given width. However, when two cells are not merged, I need to have their total width not exceed the width of the merged cells. How can I achieve the latter?

[image]

In the first table, the text in the merged cells is wrapped, which is fine.

In the second table, the text in the non-merged cells is not wrapped, which makes the table too wide.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nZUjE/).

My html is:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>xyz 1</td>  
        <td>xyz 2</td>  
        <td>xyz 3</td>  
        <td>xyz 4</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="twoColWidth">
            xyz aaaa ffffffffffffff
        </td>  
        <td colspan="2" class="twoColWidth">
            xyz bbbb fff
        </td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>xyz 1 33333 444444</td>  
        <td>xyz 2</td>  
        <td>xyz 3</td>  
        <td>xyz 4 33333 444444</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="twoColWidth">
            xyz aaaa ffffffffffffff
        </td>  
        <td colspan="2" class="twoColWidth">
            xyz bbbb fff
        </td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my CSS is:

```
.twoColWidth {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your table a fix width, and use `colgroup` with `col` to give all the columns the same width:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 175px;">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="4" width="25%" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz 1</td>  
        <td>xyz 2</td>  
        <td>xyz 3</td>  
        <td>xyz 4</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            xyz aaaa ffffffffffffff
        </td>  
        <td colspan="2">
            xyz bbbb fff
        </td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works in most cases, so good enough for me... (it does not work with some big unbreakable words, but then again, I can make the table a little larger...)

Answer (score 0):

table { width: 100px; }
just set a max width for the entire table?

Comment: Is that a question or an answer?  Elaborate and be definitive about it!

Answer (score 0):

If the tables will be always like you stated, you can try e.g. nth-child pseudo-class selector:

```
tr:nth-child(2) {
    width:20px;
}
```

It will influence always the even/second row in table.